# Group Ordering in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quotes_panels ON quotes.wp_user_id = quotes_panels.ID 
WHERE quotes.created >= '$startDate' 
AND quotes.created <= '$endDate' AND quotes.wp_user_id != '0'
```

This query can produce multiple rows from the same user (quotes.wp_user_id) but I only want to show the row which has the biggest roof area (quotes.roofarea).

However when I added GROUP BY quotes.wp_user_id it automatically takes the lowest quotes.ID row rather than the row with the biggest quotes.roofarea. When adding ORDER BY quotes.roofarea DESC to the end of the query it ordered the entire results not just the results of the "GROUP BY".

Can anyone assist with getting the desired results for the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quotes_panels ON quotes.wp_user_id = quotes_panels.ID 
WHERE quotes.created >= '$startDate' 
AND quotes.created <= '$endDate' AND quotes.wp_user_id != '0'
AND quotes.roofarea = (SELECT MAX(q.roofarea) FROM quotes q WHERE q.wp_user_id = quotes.wp_user_id)
GROUP BY quotes.wp_user_id
```

Check Now

Comment: Thanks for the query, but its not grouping correctly as two rows from the same user are still shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to order the rows before you group them.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quotes_panels ON quotes.wp_user_id = quotes_panels.ID 
WHERE quotes.created >= '$startDate' 
AND quotes.created <= '$endDate' AND quotes.wp_user_id != '0' 
ORDER BY quotes.roofarea DESC) a 
GROUP BY a.wp_user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, I am trying it but receiving the following error: "database error Duplicate column name 'ID'"

Comment: This might be caused by the * in the inner SELECT statement. Try to list the needed fields instead of the *. There is a column named ID in both tables. quotes and quotes_panels. SQL doesn't know which one to select.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL `GROUP BY` is done before `ORDER BY`, so you would need to do this in two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM quotes 
    INNER JOIN quotes_panels ON quotes.wp_user_id = quotes_panels.ID 
    WHERE quotes.created >= '$startDate' 
    AND quotes.created <= '$endDate' AND quotes.wp_user_id != '0'
    ORDER BY quotes.roofarea DESC) AS subset
GROUP BY subset.wp_user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, I am trying it but receiving the following error: "database error Duplicate column name 'ID'"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT *, MAX(quotes.roofarea) FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quotes_panels ON quotes.wp_user_id = quotes_panels.ID 
WHERE quotes.created >= '$startDate' 
AND quotes.created <= '$endDate' AND quotes.wp_user_id != '0'
GROUP BY quotes.wp_user_id
```

Read more about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the query, it groups the rows correctly but does not pick the row with the highest quotes.roofarea for some reason?

Comment: @ElliotReeve What datatype is quotes.roofarea of?

Comment: @ElliotReeve It picks the highest quotes.roofarea for every wp_user_id. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I have chosen the correct answer for what I was looking for.